# docbook saxon toolchain extension jar file -- cannot find same

Tags: saxon, docbook, docbook-xsl

To set up the docbook toolchain with Saxon, in our classpath,
I understand we need a JAR file with some extensions.
Now I can't find it on the internet.

Here is the information from Bob Stayton's wonderful book on "Docbook: XSL"

The DocBook stylesheets have some custom extension functions written specifically for the Saxon processor. These functions are contained in a saxon653.jar file that is included with the DocBook distribution in its extensions subdirectory. There may be several saxon jar files there, labeled by the version number of Saxon. Use the one closest to your Saxon version number. See the section “DocBook Saxon and Xalan extensions” for a more complete description of the DocBook Saxon extensions.

I had all this set up on the Computer Science server at the University where
I teach.   Unfortunately, that server was lost.  I am trying to recreate
the toolchain.  I use docbook to create the class notes for two of my courses.   And I need this to set up my classes for the Spring 2017 semester.

Answer (score 0):

I located this in the sourceforge docbook project under files

`docbook-xsl-saxon-1.00`

NOT the `docbook-xsl-doc-1.79.1.zip` to which webpage points

Comment: If you have downloaded **docbook-xsl-1.79.1.zip**, then you already have the JAR file with the Saxon extensions. It is called `saxon65.jar` and is in the `extensions` subdirectory. You do not need to download docbook-xsl-saxon-1.00 separately.